# How to set UIWebView initial position?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview, offset

How to set the initial focus in a HTML page using UIWebView. For example, below is the HTML page. If i load this in UIWebView, it shows from (0,0) coordinates of a HTML view. But i want to change the starting position as described in the below image. I tried to change the offset, but no use.

webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(100, 100).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't hard code this because for one reason, it's hard-coded. If google, or whatever website you want to display alters their layout your positions will be obsolete. And you will have to resubmit your entire app just to off-set this.

My recommendation is use auto layout and 'scales page to fit' for the `UIWebView`.

But your code is accurate. Make sure you put it in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` or `viewDidLoad` and your `UIWebViewDelegate` & `UIScrollViewDelegate` are added to your header file and called in your implementation file :

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I mentioned Google.com for example.. I have to change the offset for a PDF file.. corrected in my question as well..

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the UIWebView into a subview.  A generic UIView will work.
2. When instantiating the UIWebView, give it screen bounds with a slightly lower width than the containing UIView.  Weird, I know.
3. Set the UIWebView's contentOffset in the webViewDidFinishLoad method of your UIWebViewDelegate

The following code works for me, in Xcode 6.1.1.  To test, just make this ViewController class the root view controller for your app:

```
   import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

        override func loadView () {

            let screenBounds : CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

            var slimmerBounds : CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            slimmerBounds.size.width = slimmerBounds.size.width - 1

            let webView = UIWebView(frame: slimmerBounds)
            let url = NSURL (string: "http://google.com/")
            let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            webView.loadRequest(req)
            webView.delegate = self;
            let contentView = UIView(frame: screenBounds)
            contentView.addSubview(webView)
            self.view = contentView
        }

        func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
            webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 100)
            webView.bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        }
    }
```

By the way ... this will set the initial position of **all** URLs loaded into this Web view.  If you only want to position the first page, you'll need to add some additional logic to `webViewDidFinishLoad`